# Center twitter embed iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, twitter

I'm using the Twitter oembed api, and now have the following code on my page:

```
<div class='row'>

   <iframe id="twitter-widget-0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" class="twitter-tweet twitter-tweet-rendered" style="display: block; max-width: 99%; min-width: 220px; padding: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; margin: 10px 0px; border-color: rgb(238, 238, 238) rgb(221, 221, 221) rgb(187, 187, 187); border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902) 0px 1px 3px; position: static; visibility: visible; width: 500px;" title="Embedded Tweet" height="186"></iframe>
   <script async="" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EzeG2/

Basically all I'm trying to do is center horizontally the iframe in the .row, but only with CSS, because I don't control any of the styles that are inlined with the iframe. `margin:0 auto;` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to assume that you can't change the inline styles of this iFrame for my answer.

The problem is that your inline styles are overriding your `margin: 0 auto;` class. A fix for this would be to throw `!important` onto to your `margin: 0 auto;` class like so..

```
.row iframe{
    margin:0 auto !important;
    display:block;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EzeG2/2/)

If you can edit the inline styles of the iFrame, then you could remove the `margin:10px 0px;` or edit that be your desired result of `margin: 10px auto;`

Comment: Your suggestion should work. just a minor comment; `display: block` is already inline. so it's not needed for the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I can work out, the only reason the code does not work as it is is becaulse you have

```
frameborder="0"
```

on the iframe which counters out the margin: 0 auto, and you are missing a " after

```
style="display: block
```

in the inline styles.

If you are unable to change inline styles, then add !important after 0 auto like such:

```
margin:0 auto !important;
```